# Stove top too hot after replacing oven insulation

Tags: insulation, oven

A mouse ruined the insulation in my stove, so I called a repair guy to replace it. I really have no idea whether he used a factory approved replacement, but the company said he would. Now the stove top gets very hot when the oven is on. I’m worried it will damage the burner wiring and maybe the adjoining cabinets. And the kitchen gets uncomfortably warm. Do you think if I bought another batt of insulation and doubled up, would that work and would it be safe?

Comment: do you really want people to guess if your stove would be safe?  ... obviously the replacement was done incorrectly

Comment: Manufacturer/model # *might* help.

Comment: Would call them back with your concerns.  If they are a good company/repair person they will come back and check the work.